# Can't install STATA 15 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I am having problems installing STATA 15 in Ubuntu 18.04. See below.

What do I need to do?

It seems that stata was initialized, but then when I typed `./stata` or `./xstata`, I was not able to open since a the package was missing. See below

Stata is initialized.
You should now, as superuser, verify that you can enter Stata by typing

```
# ./stata
```

or

```
# ./xstata
```

It makes no difference, but `xstata` requires X windows to work, so perhaps
you should use `stata`.

To exit Stata, at Stata's dot prompt, type

```
.exit
```

Continuing with the instructions in the Installation Guide

```
root@mrilab01:/usr/local/stata15# ./stata
```

the following error does occur:

```
./stata: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0:
```

cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What can I do?

Comment: Missing "libpng12.so.0" : Download the old Ubuntu 16* package `libpng12-0`  http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb     ... and install it : `sudo gdebi Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Solution : Download the old Ubuntu 16* package libpng12-0 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

.... and install the package

```
sudo gdebi Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```